# Are "boundary" conditions of a sequence of functions preserved in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have a bounded sequence of functions in $$A=\{\xi\in H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}),\ \  \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\xi(x)=1,\ \  \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\xi(x)=0\},$$
say $\{\xi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Since the functions are in $H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ they are continuous. By a diagonal argument I constucted a subsequence of $\{\xi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which is convergent pointwise a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$ and weakly in $H^1(K)$ for any fixed compact $K$. Now this limit, say $\xi$, is in $H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ thus it is continuous. I have one question:
Does $\xi\in A$? I wanted to prove this by an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument but fixing $\epsilon>0$ gives me $M_n>0$ s.t. $\vert 1-\xi_n(x)\vert<\epsilon$, when $x>M_n$, but I have no additional informations on this sequence $M_n$.

Comment: Not necessarily: $\frac{1}{2}(1+\tanh{(x-n)})$ converges pointwise to $0$, and weakly to $0$ on compacta (indeed, on a given compact set the convergence is uniform).

Comment: @Chappers Mm, this is not good. Would the answer be negative even if I have some additional condition like $\xi_n(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, $\forall n$?

Comment: Sadly that's still not good enough: you can add on a bump function to satisfy a condition at $x=0$.

Comment: When you say your sequence is "bounded", what do you actually mean by that?

Comment: @PhoemueX I mean this: Given a compact $K$ $\exists M>0$ constant depending on K s.t. $\vert\vert \xi_n\vert\vert_{H^1(K)}<M$, $\forall n$. I need this assumption in order to use weak precompacteness of $H^1(K)$ and to extract my subsequence by a diagonal arument.